# Adding series to chart for each new range row

Tags: excel, vba, charts, series, range

I need to create a chart which consists of multiple series that have only one pair of values.
it looks something like this:

[image]

Picture is showing six series of one coordinate.

The names of series and values are taken from cells of three different ranges (each range have  only one column and all paired data are in the same row but different ranges).

Buttons are created which triggers adding/deleting rows and resizing ranges accordingly.

Is it possible to add/delete series for each new resize of ranges? Even if it means deleting existing chart every time and drawing new. 
Basically it is needed to count rows of ranges and for each row to have series.

Hope that I managed to explain myself. I would be grateful for any pointers.

Comment: It would be great if you could somehow show the source range layout; how it looks before and after data source range changes if it is dynamic that is. And most importantly, if you could also add the things that you've tried? That would be awesome.